# SQL Server Timeout

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a service that talks to **local** instance of SQL Server. I am getting an error

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
>   A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

This error happens intermittently. Since this is part of my continuous integration process its painful as I have to carry out whole build process again.

I would like to make this clear that I am not getting the issue every time its random in nature.

Please help me with this.

Comment: "Please help me with this.
" - not much to go on. You have an intermittent problem; we have not enough information.

Comment: Are you connection to the database with a ASP.net site, a win forms app, and PHP site. What are you using :)? what kind of queries/sp's are you calling?

Comment: I am trying to connect through a windows service.

Comment: Can you **show us** the connection string as a starting point?? What version / edition of SQL Server are you using - Express? Web? Standard?

Comment: Initial Catalog=BizTalkRuleEngineDb;Data Source=CIAGENT40;Integrated Security=SSPI;
This is the connection string. and I am using Sql Server 2005

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried toggling the various connection interfaces via the SQL Server Confoguration tool? I suspect you may be connecting via TCP/IP, which could be the subject of network issues elsewhere. Because you're local to the server, you could disable that interface and force the use of Shared Memory, which should help you troubleshoot the problem.

For more information on the connection types, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187892.aspx